# Word for "willing to try new and unfamiliar things"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Example:

> A: Hey, do you like to do bungee jumping?
>
> B: Um, OK. Haven't done it before, but let's try it.

I'm not looking for adventurous or something similar. That word should also fit in less action-packed activities:

> A: I have a new board game. Do you like to play?
>
> B: I don't know this game and, actually, I don't like these varieties of games but I'll play. Maybe it's fun.

First I thought about *open-minded* but I think this means more *willing to listen to people, think about their ideas, arguments, ... and accept them (not necessarily agree)*.

What word describes person who is willing to try activities he doesn't know or hasn't experienced before?

Comment: "Open-minded" usually means willing to listen to competing ideas, as in philosophical, political, religious, etc, as opposed to trying a new sport. (Well, many people seem to use "open-minded" to mean "agrees with me" and "close-minded" to mean "disagrees with me", but that's another story.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be *[adventurous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/adventurous)* is to be willing to try new things (not necessarily action-packed).

Comment: Indeed. I thought I was adventurous when I ate frog for the first time.

Comment: Some say *adventurous*, others say *foolhardy*.

Answer (score 14):

A slightly obscure alternative: [Neophile](http://www.reference.com/browse/wiki/Neophile)

Answer (score 11):

*[Uninhibited](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/uninhibited)* often is used in the sense you ask for.  Near-synonyms include *unrestrained, unchecked, uncontrolled, unfettered, free, unbound, unconstrained, wild or unruly, unbridled, boundless, limitless, unstultified.*

Regarding *[adventurous](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/adventurous)* I prefer form *[venturesome](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/venturesome)* (or perhaps  *[adventuresome](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/adventuresome)*) but the meaning is nearly the same.

Also consider *[audacious](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/audacious)* (in senses "Disposed to venture or take risks" or daring) and *[dauntless](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/dauntless)* (with its several "fearless, intrepid, bold, audacious" senses).

Answer (score 9):

In a less formal context, [game](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/game_3) is sometimes used as an adjective to mean *"willing to do something, esp something different, new, or slightly dangerous"*

Comment: +1 I think this is the best answer, particularly given the question's emphasis on applicability to less action-packed activities. I don't think its use needs to be restricted to less formal contexts though.

Answer (score 4):

[Openness to experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openness_to_experience) is a term used in the [Five Factor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) of personality. Based on this, I use the term *open to experience* or simply *open*.

Answer (score 2):

**[Philoneism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/philoneism)** an excessive love of novelty.

Answer (score 0):

[Inquisitive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inquisitive?searchDictCode=all) might be an alternative.

Comment: Don't know why someone already downvoted this answer (perhaps because it has two different meanings, one of which is considered disapproving), but I think this is a good suggestion.