# What is another word for "likes to try new things"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who likes to try new things. Any suggestions?

Comment: See this item: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/word-for-willing-to-try-new-and-unfamiliar-things
"Adventurous" was suggested there.

Comment: "Adventurous" sounds like the person is willing to randomly walk into a forest or something.

Comment: New activities that might seem interesting, like sports, classes, or hobbies.

Comment: The hard thing is the single-word aspect.The answer given has a single word, but I think `neophile` would be pretty obscure to the average person. Maybe `receptive`, but it might come across as too clinical for what you want, and could be better suited to ideas put to them rather than someone who actively seeks out new things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context, consider:

> *Novelty seeker*
>
> *Experimenter*
>
> *Thrill seeker*
>
> *Innovator*
>
> *Instigator*
>
> *Initiator*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
>
> *Entrepreneur*

Answer (score 4):

You might consider *neophile* or *neophiliac*.  The OED defines *neophilia* as:

> **neophilia** /niːəˈfɪlɪə/.
>
> Love for, or great interest in, what is new; a love of novelty. So **neoˈphiliac**, a person characterized by neophilia; also **neoˈphili(a)c** a.; **neˈophily**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add also:

- Pioneer  (a pioneer in the field of scientific research)
- Creator  ( a creator of a new technology)
- Explorer (an explorer  keen on making new geographical discoveries)