# Expression for personality/lifestyle of somebody that likes to step outside of the comfort zone?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expression-choice

This is maybe a difficult question. In my mother tongue we have a word for it, but I can not find anything similar in english:

How to describe a person/characteristic/way of life of somebody that enjoys life, tries out new things, goes to new places, is always curious etc. Simply said **somebody that thinks and acts out of the comfort zone in daily life**.
(And that does not have to be something major, could also be the small things in life)

Things I was thinking about are words like
**adventurous**, but that is so "big" and to me it implies that that person travels the world, but I am looking for something that could apply easily to somebody that decides to try out a new lunch place in stead of eating at home, just because. Or 
**a go-getter**, but that is to aggressive
Or a way to describe the lifestyle, like '**having a happy lifestyle**' or '**exploring lifestyle**', but that is so vague..

Best so far: '*somebody that lives curiously*' but I am looking for alternatives. Please help :)

Comment: How about *daredevil*?

Comment: You could say he's a [thrill-seeker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrill-seeker), but that often implies being prone to take *physical risks*. There's always [neophile](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/neophile) for someone who's obsessed with novelty.

Comment: I have a few words that come close to describe the character of a person you described.
Avent-garde;
Pioneer;
Trailblazer.

Comment: Would you share the word in your language?

Comment: Love the concept.  English poorly represents this approach to life.  Outgoing, extrovert emphasize social effects.  Pushing the envelope, adventurous, maverick, enterprising, resourceful point to changes in the outer world.  Neophile, novelty-seeking, daredevil come closer but seem joyless, and miss the vulnerability you portray so well.  None capture self-driven, deliberate unfamiliarity for its own reward.  Please will you name this **word in your mother tongue**?  Perhaps English should steal it.  I want to.

Comment: Related question: [Word for “willing to try new and unfamiliar things”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/word-for-willing-to-try-new-and-unfamiliar-things)

Answer (score 2):

An *[enterprising](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enterprising)* person takes on the adventures of life:

> adjective
>
> 1. ready to undertake projects of importance or difficulty, or untried schemes; energetic in carrying out any undertaking:
>
> *Business is in need of enterprising young people.*
>
> 2. characterized by great imagination or initiative:
>
> *an enterprising foreign policy.*
>
> from dictionary.reference.com

Its synonyms line up well:

> 1. *[venturous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/venturous)*
> 2. *[venturesome](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/venturesome)*
> 3. *[resourceful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resourceful)*
> 4. *[adventurous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adventurous)*
>
> from dictionary.reference.com

*Enterprising* has picked up commercial connotations, but they are all closely related to the adventurous idea of its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=enterprising&searchmode=none):

> "***eager to undertake, prompt to attempt***," 1610s, present participle
> adjective from the verb *enterprise* (late 15c.),
>
> from the noun [*enterprise*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=enterprise&allowed_in_frame=0).
>
> early 15c., "*an undertaking*," formerly also *enterprize*,
>
> from Old French *enterprise* "*an undertaking*," noun use of fem. past
> participle of *entreprendre* "*undertake, take in hand*" (12c.),
>
> from *entre*- "*between*" (see entre-) + *prendre* "*to take*,"
> contraction of *prehendere* (see prehensile).
>
> Abstract sense of "*adventurous disposition*, *readiness to undertake
> challenges*, *spirit of daring*" is from late 15c.
>
> from etymonline.com ***emphasis*** mine

*Enterprising* captures most of *adventurous* with the added value of *productive value* and less of the *daredevil* connotations.

Answer (score 1):

If *adventurous* seems to you to overshoot the mark you might try *venturesome:* per OED, “Of persons: Disposed or ready to venture or take risks; bold, daring; = VENTUROUS *adj.”*

Answer (score 1):

I think ***outgoing*** is the most suitable word. It suggests being sociable and friendly but it is stepping out of your comfort zone in an extended sense. Another similar word is ***extrovert***.

---

> So you want to be outgoing? This may require you to step out of your comfort zone and do things that you would not normally do. You will need to talk more, try new things and enjoy life more. It is a great trait to have and allows you to experience life to the fullest and to enjoy everything that life has to offer.
>
> [How to Be Outgoing?](http://www.healthguidance.org/entry/15340/1/How-to-Be-Outgoing.html) / *healthguidance.org*

Answer (score 0):

When somebody steps out of his comfort zone, he runs risks, big or small. You try a new restaurant, there's always the possibility you won't like the food at all. You want to try a new drug a friend said is fantastic, it may be fatal. I would then suggest the phrase "a risk-taking behavior"

- "He has always had a risk-taking behavior."

But if you mean the consequences are trivial, I suggest

- "He is a novelty-seeker." or, even better, "He likes to try novelties."

> - "novelty" - (noun) something that is new or unusual, something novel
>     something unusual and entertaining that is popular for a short period of time. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novelty)

Answer (score 0):

You could say he *[pushes the envelope](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+the+envelope)*:

> **Push the envelope:**
>
> Exceed the limits of what is normally done, be innovative, as in *They are pushing the envelope in using only new fabrics for winter clothing*.
>
> This idiom comes from aviation, the envelope alluding to the technical limits of a plane's performance, which, on a graph, appear as a rising slope as limits of speed and stress are approached and falls off when the capacity is exceeded and the pilot loses control; safety lies within these limits, or envelope, and exceeding them exposes pilot and plane to risk. [Slang; late 1960s]
>
> The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

**[maverick](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maverick)**

> A person who shows independence of thought and action, especially by refusing to adhere to the policies of a group

> An unbranded range animal, a calf that has become separated from its mother [Possibly after Samuel Augustus Maverick, (1803-1870), American cattleman who left the calves in his herd unbranded]

Answer (score 0):

Intrepid

"fearlessly facing up to danger, risk, or hardship"

Answer (score 0):

**[Sensation seeking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking)** is summarised by Wikipedia as:

> a personality trait defined by the search for experiences and feelings, that are "varied, novel, complex and intense", and by the readiness to "take physical, social, legal, and financial risks for the sake of such experiences." Risk is not an essential part of the trait, as many activities associated with it are not risky.

**[Novelty seeking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_seeking)** is summarised by Wikipedia as:

> a personality trait associated with exploratory activity in response to novel stimulation, impulsive decision making, extravagance in approach to reward cues, and quick loss of temper and avoidance of frustration.

Such a person might be a "sensation seeker" or "novelty seeker".